# Creating abstract data type in Java

Tags: java, collections, reference, hashset

I need to create a set, which will hold the intersection of two sets. If a value present in one of these sets is changed, intersectionSet should be affected as well.

Set up for testing :

```
Set<Integer> testSet1 = new HashSet<>();
testSet1.add(1);
testSet1.add(2);
testSet1.add(3);

Set<Integer> testSet2 = new HashSet<>();
testSet2.add(2);
testSet2.add(4);
```

If I implement intersectionSet this way, it would not be affected even if testSet1 or testSet2 get changed.

```
Set<Integer> intersectionSet = new HashSet<>(testSet1);
intersectionSet.removeIf(element -> !testSet2.contains(element));
```

If I implement it this way, upon creating intersectionSet, testSet1 or testSet2 will be modified by .removeIf(), but what here is only remove a reference to the value from intersectionSet.

```
Set<Integer> intersectionSet;
intersectionSet = testSet1;
intersectionSet.removeIf(element -> !testSet2.contains(element));
```

In general, intersectionSet should ony hold refereces to values from testSet1 and testSet2 which suit the condition.

The question is, how could I implement intersectionSet that it would be dependent on testSet1 and testSet2 (and their content) and wouldn't change them.

I'm need something like this:

```
System.out.println(testSet1.contains(1)); // print true

IntersectionSet intersectionSet = new IntersectionSet(testSet1, testSet2);

System.out.println(testSet1.contains(1)); // print true
System.out.println(testSet2.contains(4)); // print true
System.out.println(intersectionSet.contains(2)); // print true

testSet1.remove(2);

System.out.println(intersectionSet.contains(2)); // print false
```

My code is below:

```
interface OMOSetView {
    boolean contains(int element); // test if element is in set

    int[] toArray(); //return copy of elemets from set in array

    OMOSetView copy(); //return copy of set

    int size(); //return size of set

    HashSet<Integer> getSet(); //retunrn set
}

// class which represents common set, defines methods add/remove
class OMOSet implements OMOSetView {
    private HashSet<Integer> omoSet = new HashSet<>();

    public void add(int element) {
        if (!omoSet.contains(element)) {
            omoSet.add(element);
        }
    }

    public void remove(int element) {
        if (omoSet.contains(element)) {
            omoSet.remove(element);
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(int element) {
        return omoSet.contains(element);
    }

    public int[] toArray() {
        int[] array = new int[omoSet.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer element : omoSet) {
            array[i] = element;
            i++;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public OMOSet copy() {
        OMOSet copySet = new OMOSet();
        for (Integer element : omoSet) {
            copySet.add(element);
        }
        return copySet;
    }

    public int size() {
        return omoSet.size();
    }

    public HashSet<Integer> getSet() {
        return this.omoSet;
    }

}

    // class represents intersectionSet of two sets A and B
class OMOSetIntersection implements OMOSetView {
    private HashSet<Integer> intersectionSet;

    OMOSetIntersection(OMOSetView setA, OMOSetView setB) {
        intersectionSet = setA.getSet();                              // it's not working
        intersectionSet.removeIf(element -> !setB.contains(element)); // it's not working
    }

    public boolean contains(int element) {
        return intersectionSet.contains(element);
    }

    public int[] toArray() {
        int[] array = new int[intersectionSet.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer element : intersectionSet) {
            array[i] = element;
            i++;
        }
        return array;
    }

    public OMOSet copy() {
        OMOSet copySet = new OMOSet();
        for (Integer element : intersectionSet) {
            copySet.add(element);
        }
        return copySet;
    }

    public int size() {
        return intersectionSet.size();
    }

    public HashSet<Integer> getSet() {
        return intersectionSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: ...yes?  Is there a question here?

Comment: @LouisWasserman edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wrappers that implement delayed computations: this means that they do not hold the actual intersection elements but rather keep references to original sets and provide intersection on request.

Google Guava provides a large set of collection utilities that delay computations. In your case [`com.google.common.collect.Sets#intersection(Set<E> set1, Set<?> set2)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-) is a way to go:

```
Set<Integer> testSet1 = new HashSet<>();
testSet1.add(1);
testSet1.add(2);
testSet1.add(3);

Set<Integer> testSet2 = new HashSet<>();
testSet2.add(2);
testSet2.add(4);

Set<Integer> intersectionSet = Sets.intersection(testSet1, testSet2);
```

Comment: Is there any other solution? I also have to implement complementSet ( complSet = A \ B) and set which will hold only even integers from original set, so I wold like to know a little more common solution. This task is from my university homework, so it could be resolveable without Google Guava.

Comment: You have 2 options: either do it all by yourself according to my explanation at the beginning of the answer, or have a pick at Guava's collection utils source code

Comment: Main idea: you have to provide your own implementation of `Set` interface

Comment: I'm doing it already and two problems I have run into are: 1. IntersectionSet do not react on changing of one of original sets, or 2. Removing element from IntersectionSet is also affect one of original set.

Comment: I don't see any custom class like `public class IntersectionSet implements Set` in your code...

Comment: First option you suggested doesn't seem to be working for my situation.

Comment: Well, it will be kind of big, but I will try to write it here in a moment.

Comment: Your solution was helpful for me. Thank you.